# Salesforce : How to activate Apex Classes feature in Professional Edition

Tags: class, salesforce, apex

I am working on a salesforce project and need to add a package. The issue is that under developer console I am not able to create Apex Classses , which leads to the following error when I add the package to salesforce.

[This is the error I get when I try to install the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dk3By.jpg)

After reading many forums, I came to a conclusion that i need to activate Apex Author permission under permission sets. 
But the permission is not present there.

I created a developer account for salesforce in which the Apex Classes where already active and was able to import the package and make changes.

The Salesforce account is Professional Edition and is not under trial.

Any help regarding this will be appretiated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Professional Edition (PE) does not have the ability to create, modify, or deploy Apex classes directly in an org of that edition. This includes using Apex in an unmanaged package. The *Author Apex* permission is only found in Enterprise, Unlimited, Performance, and Developer editions.

If you are an AppExchange Partner, you can write apps that use Apex, and send them through security review to be installed in PE orgs (as well as Group Edition).

From the Apex Code Developer guide relating to Apex and PE, you can read about the [basic statement about Apex and supported editions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm). In the ISV Developer Guide (for App Exchange Apps and partners), you can read the specifics of what is required to [get your app to run](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/dev_packages_apex_ge_pe.htm) with Apex in a PE/GE org.

If you are exploring Salesforce for the purposes of writing ISV apps for Salesforce, I would also recommend taking this short [self-paced learning module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/isvforce_basics) on ISV basics and Salesforce on the Trailhead learning platform.

Finally, there is a dedicated [Salesforce stack exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) you might also look into for further question.